# how to make a folder named as sth that we read before in a text file by linux terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I have a text file that contains a folder name.I want to read that text file's context via Ubuntu terminal and make a folder with that name(which is written in the txt file).I don't know what to do,I have made a file named "in.txt" that its context is "name" and i have tried the c code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
FILE *fopen (const char in.txt, const char r+);
}
```

What should i write in the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have text file called `in.txt` which contains

```
Rambo
Johnny
Jacky
Hulk
```

Next you need to read word by word from file, for that you can use `fscanf()`. Once word is read, you need to create a folder with that word name. To create a folder command is `mkdir`. Next you need to execute `mkdir` from file for that you use either `system()` or `execlp()`.

Here is the simple C program

```
int main(){
        FILE *fp = fopen ("in.txt", "r");
        if(fp == NULL) {
                /* write some message that file is not present */
                return 0;
        }
        char buf[100];
        while(fscanf(fp,"%s",buf) > 0) {
                /* buf contains each word of file */
                /* now create that folder use execlp */
                if(fork() ==0 )
                        execlp("/bin/mkdir","mkdir",buf,NULL); /* this will create folder with name available in file */
                else
                        ;
        }
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
}
```

Note that `mkdir` fails if directory already exists.
Compile like `gcc -Wall test.c` and execute it like `./a.out` it will create the folders.

**EDIT :** Same If you want to using `open()` system call, there you won't any system calls which reads word by words like so you need to string manipulation.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int inputfd = open("in.txt",O_RDONLY);
        perror("open");
        if (inputfd == -1) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* first find the size of file */
        int pos = lseek(inputfd,0,2);
        printf("pos = %d \n",pos);
        /* againg make inputfd to point to beginning */
        lseek(inputfd,0,0);
        /*allocate memory equal to size of file, not random 1024 bytes */
        char *buf = malloc(pos);
        read(inputfd,buf,pos);/* read will read whole file data at a time */
        /* you need to find the words from the buf, bcz buf contain whole data not one word */
        char cmd[50];/* buffer to store folder name */
        for(int row = 0,index = 0; buf[row]; row++) {
                if(buf[row]!=' ' && buf[row]!='\n') {
                        cmd[index] = buf[row];
                        index++;
                        continue;
                }
                else {
                        cmd[index] = '\0';
                        index = 0;/* for next word, it should start from cmd[0] */
                        if(fork() == 0 )
                                execlp("/bin/mkdir","mkdir",cmd,NULL);
                        else ;
                }
        }
        close(inputfd);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes that works,and what can i do if i want to use systemcalls to this process not the c library, I mean how to use "int open(const char * filename, int flags, int mode) "instead of" fopen"?

Comment: yes thats possible & that will advisable if you are implementing same using `open()`. you need to use `read()` call instead of `fscanf()`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work:[Error] 'fork' was not declared in this scope

Comment: And make sure you call like `if( fork() == 0 )` not `if( fork == 0 )`, sometimes happens.

Comment: yes its my code:

  int inputfd = open("in.txt",O_RDONLY);

  if (inputfd == -1) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
 void *buf = (char*) malloc(1024);
        while(read(inputfd,buf,1024) > 0) {
            
                if(fork() ==0 )
                        execlp("/bin/mkdir","mkdir",buf,NULL); 
                else
                        ;
        }

Comment: I edit my answer @beginner for simplification. there are lot of bugs like check your `main()` prototype(instead of `argv[]` it should be `*argv[]`) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let the text file `in.txt` be:

```
foldername1
foldername2
```

Then you can create a script file `script.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# $1 will be replaced with the first argument passed to the script:
mkdir -p $(cat "$1")
```

Run the script in the shell as: `./script.sh in.txt`. The folder names specified in `in.txt` should now be available. This assumes one file name per line in `in.txt` without space.

Comment: `mkdir -p $(cat in.txt)` just in case they store lines like foldername1/test

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you want to perform other commands besides mkdir

```
while read -r line; do mkdir -p $line && chown www-data:www-data $line; done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **for** loop from Linux terminal like:

`for line in $(cat in.txt); do mkdir $line; done`

That should work fine to create multiple files.